# Django (1.6) + Apache2

Tags: django, apache

First time I setup Django and Apache, and I'm having a tough time. It's seems easy by following tutorials, but it doesn't seem to work.

Basically, the steps I followed (on Debian):

Install Django (and some libraries)

Install Apache2

Install mod_wsgi

Then I've put my Django app in /root/, so the path is something like :

```
root/
 .Projet/
   .myprojet/
     .site/
     . .#here the models.py, views.py, etc of my site
     .myprojet/
     . .#here the settings.py, wsgi.py
     . .static/
     .   .#static files in folders
     .templates
     . .#my templates
     .database.sql
     .manage.py
```

Then in /etc/apache2 I created the file httpd.conf, with this inside :

```
WSGIScriptAlias / /root/Projet/myprojet/myprojet/wsgi.py
WSGIPythonPath /root/Projet/myprojet
<Directory /root/Projet/myprojet/myprojet>
  <Files wsgi.py>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
  </Files>
</Directory>
```

I do a2enmod wsgi (it tells me "Module wsgi already enabled").
Then service apache2 restart (successful, but tells me I have no VirtualHosts).

When I go to my website (using the IP adress), just the Apache "It works" display.

Thank you for your help ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't put your Apache configuration file in `/etc/apache2/`. The fact that you mention `a2enmod` implies that you are on a Debian-based distro like Ubuntu. For those systems, you need to give that file a name related to the app - call it `django` if you like - and put it in `/etc/apache2/sites-available`. Then you can run `a2ensite django` to link it to sites-enabled, restart Apache, and it should work.

Comment: Oh indeed. Many thanks.
Now I have "403 Forbidden" but I guess it's a good start :)

Comment: 403 Forbidden wasn't too much of a big deal, reading the error.log and access.log. It was a simple problem of file permissions (had to grant enough permissions to access the folder where my project is, or move it elsewhere requiring less).
Thank you again :)